# Get ros2 Service Client ID

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

To give some back ground , I have multiple Service Client like this in the [picture - 2nd gif](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Services/Understanding-ROS2-Services.html#background). These clients will modify some variables stored in the server. Based on some unique id of the client I would like to maintain some access control to modification the variables in  ros2 Service Server.

Is it possible to obtain the ros2 Service Client ID (unique_id) from ros2 Service Server once it receives the service request ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/373722/get-ros2-service-client-id/) by [BhanuKiran.Chaluvadi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28829/bhanukiran.chaluvadi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 241 on 2021-03-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Service call back function can be overloaded like this

```
  void handleSrv(
      const std::shared_ptr<rmw_request_id_t> requestHeader,
      const std::shared_ptr<example_interfaces::srv::AddTwoInts::Request> request,
      std::shared_ptr<example_interfaces::srv::AddTwoInts::Response> response);
```

`requestHeader` variable has all the information needed. Similarly for subscriber

```
  void handleSub(const std_msgs::msg::String::SharedPtr msg,
                                 const rclcpp::MessageInfo& message_info);
```

`message_info` variable has all the information needed.

---

Originally posted by [BhanuKiran.Chaluvadi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28829/bhanukiran.chaluvadi/) with karma: 241 on 2021-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Comment: Any chance this overload was exposed in Python? I couldn't find it